# switch aws Iam roles on RancherOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rancher

I have rancherOS running on my bootstrap node from where I want to launch aws EC2 containers. I have to switch the roles in my aws account to launch instances eg: I will be logged in as a user and have to change to admin role. On the rancher UI I can give my access and secret access keys and it is directly pointing me to use the VPC and subnets of 'user' IAM role instead I want to use 'admin' IAM role VPC and subnets. How can I change the roles in this case?
Following is where I got stuck, there I want to switch to another role in aws
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same role switch same as you do with other linux systems,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html

Append your rolename in the configuration and cli takes care from there.

In your cli use which profile you want to use, it will assume his role.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am sorry if the question isn't clear or I understood you wrong, you are specifying to change the iam roles of aws via aws configure but that doesn't work in this case because rancher dosen't get aws configure details and I have to manually give the access and secret access key on UI